# Hosting pictures with React and Google drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-drive-api, photo-gallery

I would like to host around 300 photo on Google drive and be able to fetch every photo on my react project, but I don't know how to start like should I need a back-end like node.js? I've seen this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iajv8y-6n3Q), but he **displays** only 1 photo.

I wanna display all my images from Google drive on the React and put it on a array like this following JSON

```
const photos = [
  {
    src: 'https://source.unsplash.com/2ShvY8Lf6l0/800x599',
    width: 4,
    height: 3,
    year: '2021',
    event: 'Hiking',
  },
  {
    src: 'https://source.unsplash.com/Dm-qxdynoEc/800x799',
    width: 1,
    height: 1,
    year: '2021',
    event: 'J-On',
  },
  {
    src: 'https://source.unsplash.com/qDkso9nvCg0/600x799',
    width: 3,
    height: 4,
    year: '2021',
    event: 'Language Exchange',
  },
  and so on...
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question. It made me curious. I've just updated my answer by adding `NextJS` and `googleapis` data fetching so you can fetch it automatically from google drive. I tested the app before posting the update. So, I am sure it will work if you follow the instruction.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve your goal in two ways:

1. Get the files link by **manually copying** the link from google drive
2. **Fetch the data** by using `Next.js` app and `googleapis`.

### 1. Get the files link by manually copying the link from google drive:

- Open the file on google drive
- Right click at the image file
- Click `Get Link` and a pop up will open
- At `General Access` select `Anyone with the link` and make sure the role is `Viewer`
- Click `Copy Link` and done.

Then paste it at any text editor, and you will get the link like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WS45ByTh_e8QNJTeFMGI8TYpE4OYS2U4/view?usp=sharing
```

Remove the `file/d` and replace it with `uc?export=view&id=` and remove the `/view?usp=sharing` completely and you will get something like:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1WS45ByTh_e8QNJTeFMGI8TYpE4OYS2U4
```

And put the image information in an array:

```
const images = [
    {
       name: "Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness",
       src: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1WS45ByTh_e8QNJTeFMGI8TYpE4OYS2U4"
    }
]
```

Please do the same with the other files, and your images constant finally looks like this:

```
const images = [
  {
    name: "Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness",
    src:
      "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1WS45ByTh_e8QNJTeFMGI8TYpE4OYS2U4",
  },
  {
    name: "Minions: The Rise of Gru",
    src:
      "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1eUvlVjwp2brHnyD-cWN0x-10tuS_wXfU",
  },
  ...
  ,
  {
    name: "Fantastic Beasts: The Secrets of Dumbledore",
    src:
      "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1vU64yCMdu_ns4xPP-VMYoiJPKNietxRc",
  },
];
```

Now, it is time to render the images in our React Application by using javascript's map method:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>My Google Drive Images</div>
      <ul>
        {images.map((image, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              <h1>{image.name}</h1>
              <img src={image.src} alt={image.name} />
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### 2. Fetch the data by using `Next.js` app and `googleapis`.

In case we have many photos, it is better to use data fetching. Here we use  [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) app and [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) library.

There are 3 pieces of information that we need to provide in order to be able to fetch data from `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2` server which are:

1. CLIENT_ID
2. CLIENT_SECRET
3. REFRESH_TOKEN

For `CLIENT_ID` & `CLIENT_SECRET` are OAuth 2.0 Client information that can be obtained from [Google Developers Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/). You can read the details [here](https://www.balbooa.com/gridbox-documentation/how-to-get-google-client-id-and-client-secret). And for the `REFRESH_TOKEN` can be obtained from [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and the steps are as follows:

1. Go to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
2. Click the `OAuth 2.0 Configuration` button
3. Click `Use your own OAuth credentials` checkbox
4. Fill the Client ID & Client Secret input with the OAuth 2.0 CLIENT_ID & CLIENT_SECRET that we get from [Google Developers Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).
5. Close the configuration popup by clicking the close link button.
6. Find and click the **Drive API v3** at Step 1 Select & authorizes APIs.
7. Select `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` to enable the Authorize APIs button.
8. Next we need to select which information that can be accessed by using the token that will be created by clicking the `Authorize APIs` button.
9. Then we will be directed to the `Sign in with google` page. Select the account that we used to generate the CLIENT_ID & CLIENT_SECRET.
10. If the `Google hasn’t verified this app` page appears, just click Advance and click Go to ...(unsafe) and select the access types that will be granted to our Next.js app then click `Continue` and you will be redirected to OAuth 2.0 Playground again.
11. Find the `Exchange authorization code for tokens` button at `Step 2 Exchange authorization code for tokens`, and click it to get the `Refresh token` and `Access token`
12. To make sure that we have generated the tokens correctly, go to `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}` in your browser. Our configuration is successful if there is a raw JSON page that shows our drive items.

Now, we are ready for coding. We will use our NextJs API to communicate with `googleapis` server and serve the data to be consumed by our app.

Open your Nextjs app, create a `/pages/api/drive-files.ts` file, and import `googleapis` library (here we use Typescript).

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { google } from "googleapis";
...
```

Create types:

```js
type DriveFile = {
  kind: string;
  id: string;
  name: string;
  mimeType: "image/jpeg";
};

type Data = {
  files: DriveFile[];
};
```

Add the Data type at the NextApiResponse and the handler will look like this:

```
export default async function handler(
  _req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {

  ...
}
```

Next, create `oauth2Client` that use CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET credentials and we use `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground` as the redirect uri, `setCredentials` using REFRESH_TOKEN, and return the `google.drive` response as JSON;

```js
# /pages/api/drive-files.ts

import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { google } from "googleapis";

export type DriveFile = {
  kind: string;
  id: string;
  name: string;
  mimeType: "image/jpeg";
};

export type Data = {
  files: DriveFile[];
};

const CLIENT_ID =
  "777777777777-xxxxddhsl77d7o77777xxxx0v777xx7.apps.googleusercontent.com";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "XXXXXX-777XXXX_-7-hexxxxheAzW_7mr_7_";
const REDIRECT_URI = "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground";

export default async function handler(
  _req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET,
    REDIRECT_URI
  );

  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token:
      "1//04tORk-dUiDiJCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9Ir1hzh14oOk6gQWMOafDZGvLuka578PwwmZB3UMbB2a0VdcjAbRjtelFoDU92ob_Ws50I",
  });

  const drive = google.drive({
    version: "v3",
    auth: oauth2Client,
    params: {
      q: `mimeType = 'image/jpeg'`,
    },
  });

  const response = await drive.files.list();

  res.status(200).json({ files: response.data.files as DriveFile[] });
}
```

And when you access `http://localhost:3000/api/drive-files` from the browser, you will get:

```json
{
  "files":[
    {
      kind: 'drive#file',
      id: '1eUvlVjwp2brHnyD-cWN0x-10tuS_wXfU',
      name: 'Minions: The Rise of Gru.jpg',
      mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
    },
    {
      kind: 'drive#file',
      id: '1vU64yCMdu_ns4xPP-VMYoiJPKNietxRc',
      name: 'Fantastic Beasts: The Secr.jpg',
      mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
    },
    {
      kind: 'drive#file',
      id: '1WS45ByTh_e8QNJTeFMGI8TYpE4OYS2U4',
      name: 'Doctor Strange in the M.jpg',
      mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
    }
  ]
}
```

Since we will use NextJs `Image` component, don't forget to add domain `drive.google.com` at next.config.js:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ["drive.google.com"],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Finally, you can render the images as follows:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import type { NextPage } from "next";
import axios from "axios";
import { DriveFile } from "./api/drive-files";
import Image from "next/image";

const DriveFiles: NextPage = () => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<DriveFile[]>();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/api/drive-files")
      .then((res) => {
        setFiles(res.data.files);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(files);
  }, [files]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Google Drive Files</h1>
      {files &&
        files.map((file, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <p>{file.name}</p>
              <Image
                width={200}
                height={300}
                src={`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=${file.id}`}
                alt={file.name}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};

export default DriveFiles;
```