# How to take JSON information and give it to a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The fetch request (from Google Sheets) returns `stats`, which is an array of arrays. In `stats` is a list of teams with their wins and losses (one of them looks like this `['Cannons', '4', '2']`, like you see in `teams`. I want `stats` to automatically fill in my `teams` array or give it to the `data` prop in `Table`. Thank you for your help!

```
const getSheetValues = async () => {
    const request = await fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${SHEET_ID}/values/A1:C7`,
    {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`
        }
    });
    const stats = await request.json();
    console.log(stats);
    return stats;
}

const teams = [
    {
        team: 'Cannons',
        wins: 4,
        loss: 2
    },
    {
        team: 'Rhythm',
        wins: 1,
        loss: 5
    }
]


const Standings = () => {
    return (
        <div className='cont'>
            <div className='standings'>
                <Table columns={columns} data={teams} className='tbl' />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: unclear what you want, do you want to add stats to teams array ? or do you want to just use info from teams array in table?

Comment: @dippas either one works, I want the end result would be populating my table with the stats from the Google Sheets. I suspect that adding stats to teams array would be easier. (The data inside teams array is just a placeholder for right now)

Comment: can you show the output for the stats array ?

Comment: @dippas this is what it looks like when I do console.log(stats):
['Teams', 'Wins', 'Loss']
['Cannons', '4', '2']
['Racers', '6', '0'] 

and so on.

Comment: You have to use state to achieve that. Please see some examples how to use fetch with React.

Comment: Where are you using `getSheetValues` function?

Comment: @Pipe I'm not using it anywhere right now, I don't know where to use it

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your code is still an idea. But no problem, let's do it.

Here we will use [NextJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next) to fetch the data from Google Sheet and pass the result via an API endpoint to the client-side.
Keep in mind that it *is a bad idea to show your **ACCESS_TOKEN** off publicly*. So never put the **ACCESS_TOKEN** at your client-side app.

#### Server Side

You can fetch the information from googleapis using two ways:

```js
# /api/spreadsheets/[id].js

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { id } = req.query;

  const ACCESS_TOKEN = "yaXX.A0XXXXXXXXXX0-UsdRJ3DmO_sOrM-gexCZXXXXXXXXXX9bQ-VpOF_nETNoT-yWgIaj4LgJi5NIdoXXXXXXXXXXqiE0XYuOlVvIpXD3cw_fQDhXXXXXXXXXXP9Gs-VVjHnKXXXXXXXXXX7249iEHJ2-2x8PiXXXXXXXXXXBVEFTQVRBU0ZRRTY1ZHI4MGXXXXXXXXXXYURwYUdOTjh5Z0NrQQ0163";

  const spreadsheet = await fetch(
    `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${id}/values/A1:C7`,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      },
    }
  );

  const response = await spreadsheet.json();

  res.status(200).json(response.values);
}
```

or

```js
# /api/spreadsheets/[id].js

import { google } from "googleapis";

const CLIENT_ID = "840XXXXXXXXX-o5md8ddhsXXXXXXXXXi9fhu40v5n2XX2.apps.googleusercontent.com";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "GOCSPX-XXXXXX_-1-heXXXXXXAzW_7mr_1_";
const REDIRECT_URI = "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { id } = req.query;

  const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET,
    REDIRECT_URI
  );

  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: "1//0XXXXXXXXXKS_CgYIXXXXXXXXXXF-L9Ir_MTdXXXXXXZ1V9-ZlBFXXXXdz3ywAV9XXXXXXXXXXMr6Jm9O8mvLeLXXXX8iaPSVKAc",
  });

  const sheets = google.sheets("v4");

  const spreadsheets = await sheets.spreadsheets.get({
    spreadsheetId: id,
    auth: oauth2Client,
    includeGridData: true,
  });

  const datas = spreadsheets.data.sheets[0].data[0].rowData.map((row) => {
    return row.values.map((value) => value.formattedValue);
  });

  res.status(200).json(datas);
}
```

and the response of both approaches will be the same:

```json
[
  [ 'Teams', 'Wins', 'Loss' ],
  [ 'Cannons', '4', '2' ],
  [ 'Racers', '6', '0' ]
]
```

but keep in mind that the first approach will not work when the **ACCESS_TOKEN** is expired. So, please use the last one. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72864657/hosting-pictures-with-react-and-google-drive/72866078#72866078) on how to get the **REFRESH_TOKEN**.

Next, at the client-side. Here we use **antd** [Table](https://ant.design/components/table/) component to render the data.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Table } from "antd";

export default function Home() {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState();
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("api/spreadsheets/1G8XS3aseeaIqEURr1Bt0rvogBb-hgqvAglw83b5qxSA")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (response) => {
          const columnNames = response.shift();
          setColumns(
            columnNames.map((name) => {
              // to follow antd column properties
              return {
                title: name,
                dataIndex: name.toLowerCase(),
                key: name.toLowerCase(),
              };
            })
          );

          setData(
            response.map((row, i) => {
              // to follow antd dataSource properties
              return columnNames.reduce((a, v, j) => {
                a.key = `${i + 1}`;
                a[v.toLowerCase()] = row[j];
                return a;
              }, {});
            })
          );
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>App</div>
      <Table dataSource={data} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Done.